# pull coordinate data from .csv column that has address info

Tags: python, csv, data-extraction

I have a series of .csv files with coordinate info in a specific column. Problem is, the coordinate info has address info in the same column, and not always in the same format.

```
15206 PLANK RD
BAKER, LA 70714
(30.586316235000027, -91.12488045299995)
```

or

```
LA
(31.312663324000027, -92.44567750499994)
```

So what I need to do is pull just the lat data into a new column, and the long data into a new column.
I'm sure that this is a pretty simple straight forward process, I'm just not sure how to tackle this.
I'd like to have a python script that could do this for me where I specify the column to search, and have it pull just the coordinate info into new columns in the same rows it pulls that data from.

Comment: Do you mean that you simply want to ignore lines which do not contain the coordinates?

Comment: No, I just need to extract to coordinate info in to new columns in the same row, so I don't lose other attribute data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little snippet which can extract long/lat fields from a desired column. It uses a regex expression to extract the two coordinates from the given column.

```
output = []
with open(DATA_CSV_NAME, 'rb') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datareader:
        m = re.search('\((-?\d+\.\d+),\s(-?\d+\.\d+)\)', row[DESIRED_COLUMN])
        lat = m.group(1) if m else '0.0'
        long = m.group(2) if m else '0.0'
        row.append(lat)
        row.append(long)
        output.append(row)
```

Here's an example of the regex at work:

```
>>> m = re.search('\((-?\d+\.\d+),\s(-?\d+\.\d+)\)', '15206 PLANK RD\nBAKER, LA 70714\n(31.312663324000027, -92.44567750499994)')
>>> m.group(0)
'(31.312663324000027, -92.44567750499994)'
>>> m.group(1)
'31.312663324000027'
>>> m.group(2)
'-92.44567750499994'
```

Comment: This method is working for extracting the coordinate data, but isn't writing the data to a new column

Comment: There are new columns. I just didn't add the code to write out a csv, but the output array is all of the rows of data you want with columns appended as lat-long. If you want a csv file out you can simply follow the csv documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer